# PrimeNg Angular9 i am using p-tree custom api and its not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, frontend, primeng

I am trying to fill p-tree [value] with custom api how can i do it with template. this is the api

````
0: {company: "abc", name: "testGroup1",…}
company: "abc"
id: 1
name: "testGroup1"
subGroups: [{parentId: 1, name: "Business support division", id: 1}, {parentId: 1, name: "campaign", id: 3}]
0: {parentId: 1, name: "Business support division", id: 1}
id: 1
name: "Business support division"
parentId: 1
1: {parentId: 1, name: "campaign", id: 3}
id: 3
name: "campaign"
parentId: 1
1: {company: "abc", name: "testGroup2", subGroups: [{parentId: 2, name: "Billing", id: 2}], id: 2}
company: "abc"
id: 2
name: "testGroup2"
subGroups: [{parentId: 2, name: "Billing", id: 2}]
0: {parentId: 2, name: "Billing", id: 2}
id: 2
name: "Billing"
parentId: 2```
````

Comment: and what's the issue? what code is there to debug?

Comment: `<ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">
          {{ node.name }}
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template let-node pTemplate="subGroups">
          {{node.subGroups.name}}
        </ng-template>`

Comment: @Argee can you please help ???

Answer (score 0):

[image: this is as far as i can do]

now i dont know how to show the children(which is `subGroups`) of the testGroup1 and the children of testGroup2
and also show the icons